# search all comments made within the last month, and answers, to locate an interesting question?

Tags: support, comments, search

How do I search all comments within the last month?

I remember an interesting question, and of keywords in it all I recall is 2+ comments had the word project in them.  So i'd like to see all comments with that word, and thus locate the question.

I'd also like to be able to search answers.. 'cos the answer may possibly have mentioned netcat.  I found it interesting 'cos the answer talked about connecting 2 servers together. I didn't comment on it and it seems I didn't favourite it either unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to search through all recent comments - or comments between a specific date - unless you're willing to [take the API](http://api.superuser.com/1.1/usage/methods/comments) route.

You can search though your answers by typing `user:me <keywords>` in the search box. To search only answers use the condition `is:answer` in the search box. All this documentation is available in the [search page as well](https://superuser.com/search?).

Comment: Well that screenshot is clearly not it, I said, I left **no comment** on the question, and the word project is in the comments.  You only read "answer talked about connecting 2 servers together".

Comment: If you've read my answer I've talked about going through **your** comments as well as **all** comments

Comment: @Satya Well,not sure why you included that screenshot which makes it look like you found the question cos it partially matched.but it didn't match,that screenshot was not of the question.But nevertheless,thanks to other things you wrote,I found the question.  is:answer netcat,helped me find it.Also,I found I had favourited it but had to sort by "Added"it seemed to be set to sort by "Recent" and since the question was asked in 09,it didn't come up on the first pages. Added and it came up on the first page.But your is:answer found it If you can remove that screenshot then i'll accept your answer

Comment: @Sathya and I have no idea why the first sentence you wrote was "You can have a look at your recently posted comments on your User Page -> Activity -> Comments"  When I specifically said that I didn't comment on it.  It's nice info but you should have said "NOT RELEVANT BUT..." before that line. And it should not have been at the beginning as it's completely irrelevant. As is your massive screenshot which is very misleading.

Comment: +1 for containing a solution though, and it worked. I would like to accept it, and will if you can remove that screenshot.

Comment: it was meant to be a general answer. Since you don't like it, I've edited it out

Comment: It's still a general answer(and that's good), and it's no less general now, but its improvement is that it's without the misleading screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to search comments at this time. Try the google input box here:

https://superuser.com/search